# How to select from array with given probabilities?

Tags: java, arrays, random, data-generation

I have an input CSV file that looks like this:

0.2, abc, def
0.4, fgd, fol
0.4, oqo, asd

where the first column is the relative propability for a record.

Given I can read this file and put the records in an array or a list, how can I write a method in java that returns records from this array, based on their relative distribution?

**EDIT**
My goal is to create a new, bigger file that has the same distribution or records / lines as the base file.

so if i create a new file with 100 lines the absolute propability of lines should be about:
20 x line 1
40 x line 2
40 x line 3

Comment: Sum the relative probabilities.  Pick a random number within the range of the sum.  See which of the probabilities you hit.  Return the appropriate records.

Comment: Inspired by @rossums answer i will create a TreeMap `tm` with a double as key, in which i sum up all the given relative propabilities. Then i will generate a random double between 0 and the sum of relative propabilities. With  
`tm.higherEntry(randomDouble)`  
i should be able to get what i want.

Comment: "file that has the same distribution" - if you new file should have exactly this distribution, why do you do it randomly at all? You could just add 20xline1, 40xline2 and so on...

Comment: thats why i said the distribution should be about these values. Other, i want them to be returned in random fashion. I want to call a `next()` Method on the class that holds the records. After doing it 1000 times i want to get a distribution about the same as in the base file